# Best practice for indexing in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a transaction table and a inventory table that I would like to 'JOIN' together. The tables need to 'JOIN' on three primary keys.

My question is: should I create a unique key (concatenation of the three fields) and create a 'INDEX' on the unique key or would I just create a non-clustered 'INDEX' on all three fields?

I'm currently using SQL Server 2014

Comment: Pk's are usually the clustered index of the table (by default). So if you need to join on two PK's and they are clustered indices you dont need to do anything.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. The tree fields are not labeled as PK's in the DB structure. I just meant that the three fields makes a record unique and should be used to join on.

Comment: Then it could be interesting to add an index there, yes. I wouldn't go as far as create that concatenation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the Transaction table is the biggest and the Inventory is the smaller. A lot depends on what proportion of the data would you expect to be returned by your join - If its most then a table scan will probably occur so an index wont help much. If your going to try and get a small subset of date then create an index on the 3 columns on both tables and create a foreign key from Trans to Inventory on the 3 cols. (SQL Server needs an index as well as a FK)
Pick the most granular column as the first in your index as this will encourage SQL servers Optimiser to use the index.